# how to find out why our Windows 2003 webserver shows CPU use at 100%

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, cpu-usage

I am responsible for coding our web and database applications and the smooth functioning of the web server, which is running IIS6 under Windows Server 2003.   The machine's a legacy server, 2003 vintage.

For some reason the performance tab in Task Manager was showing that the server's CPU use was spiking up to 100% and staying there for 5 seconds or so, then dropping down to almost nothing, then spiking again.  None of the listed processes was consuming any CPU.

How do I find out which process is hogging the CPU like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see the CPU history of each process and to see which was the most expansive process at a certain moment of time. Note if the load is in user space or kernel space (Interrupts or DPCs). If it is kernel space you will need to upgrade the drivers or the firmware (usually the ones for the disc controller or network card).

See also:

- [Windows Performance Analysis Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance)
- [Kernrate Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463380.aspx)